# Unobstrusive javascript ajax code in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, real-time, pusher

**create.js.erb**

```
    $("#chat").append("<%= j render(@message) %>");
    $("#new_message")[0].reset();
```

I need to change this to something similar to the below:

```
function newMessage() {
    $("#chat").append("<%= j render(@message) %>");
    $("#new_message")[0].reset();
}
channel.bind('new_message', newMessage());
```

This is my ajax request call for my *create* method in *MessagesController*. I need to change like that to call this function as a callback from *index.html.erb* to use the *Pusher* server. What I want to achieve is a real-time chat application, so all clients should be abled to pushed a message without refreshing the browser.

**index.html.erb**

```
<script src="http://js.pusherapp.com/1.9/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    var pusher = new Pusher('app_key'); // Replace with your app key
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my_channel_chat');
  });
</script>
```

I think I am somehow confused with the context in create.js.erb file. Could anyone help me with this?

**Update:**

**MessagesController**

```
  def index
    @messages = Message.all
  end

  def create
    @message = current_user.messages.create!(params[:message])
    Pusher.trigger('my_channel_chat', 'new_message', {:message => @message.content})
  end
```

Comment: Do you pot a Pusher key ?

Comment: You'll need to switch from rendering server side to doing client side rendering

Comment: @FrederickCheung so that means I should get rid of MessagesController altogether, and just use javascript?

Comment: You still need the messages controller for the person submitting the message, but the point of services like pusher is the other people in the chat room get notified of updates straight from pusher.

Comment: @FrederickCheung, you helped me a lot! I fixed the problem and I will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your questions but based on what I understand this should solve your problem:

```
function newMessage() {
    $("#new_message")[0].reset();
}
$('#chat').on('new_message', newMessage);
$("#chat").append("<%= j render(@message) %>").trigger('new_message');
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! However, I don't think this would solve the problem. :(

Comment: +1 on this fixing an issue in the code. In the question you are calling the `newMessage` function when you set your event handler. This isn't want you want to do. You should pass a reference to the function, as has been indicated above.